# android app default installation set to sd card in app, but when downloaded from android market app is still installing in phone memory!

Tags: android

I have an android app whose manifest file includes android:installLocation="preferExternal" under **manifest** tag and . Now when I install the app on emulator or phone by transferring through bluetooth or adb the app is getting installed by default on SD card. I am using android 2.2 on phone.

But when I download the same app from android market the app is installing on phone memory and there is no option to move it to SD card!!!

I am wondering whats wrong with the one downloaded from android market!!! Can somebody help me to solve this issue??? I am not able to figure out the reason!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding your app and re-uploading to the market?

Comment: Yes, I have done it so many times but still not able to find why it is not working when I download from android market.

Comment: If your app is free I'll download and test to see if it's just an issue with your device.

Comment: I am using eclipse for developing android apps. I am building the app by cleaning the project in eclipse. Yes you can download my app from the market, its free... here is the link: [click here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.piapps.android.ipl4&feature=search_result)

Comment: It's doesn't give the option on my HTC Desire Stock 2.2 ROM. Sorry. I haven;t got a clue what could be wrong if you have it in the manifest tag. The only thing I can suggest is make a backup of your app, go through your manifest file and take out anything that you don't need, just in case anything there is interfering/overriding it.

Comment: Hey the problem got resolved!!! Thanks for all answers. The issue was with wrong setting in "Publishing Options" on android app store. I have set initially "Copy Protection" as ON which was blocking app to install on SD card. Now I set it to OFF and app is installed on SD card. Thanks for all help....